# Flutter/Dart: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera Path doesn't return files

Tags: flutter, dart, image-gallery

I am trying to get all the photos and videos stored in Android Phone's Gallery. I tried below code but it doesn't return any Files.

```
Future<void> getCameraDirectoryFiles() async {
  List<String> files = [];
  String path;

  path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
  String galleryPath = path + '/Camera';
  Directory directory = Directory(galleryPath);
  List<FileSystemEntity> fileList = directory.listSync(recursive: true);
  for (FileSystemEntity entity in fileList) {
    if (entity is File) {
      files.add(entity.path);
    }
  }
}
```

So Basically I got the path of DCIM directory and I appended Camera in to that and trying to get file list from Camera Directory. It doesn't show any error and simply return 0 even though I have 1000+ images in my Phone.

Note: I am testing on real Android phone and not on Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update Answer for those who encounter this issue in future.

I was trying with targetedSDK version 33 and it was not showing storage permission dialog. I was not getting files because of permission issue.

Solution: I changed targetedSDK version to 32 and it worked !

Comment: This is because on Android 13 (API 33) and above, this permission is deprecated and always returns `PermissionStatus.denied`. Instead use `Permission.photos`, `Permission.video`, `Permission.audio` or `Permission.manageExternalStorage`.